# for loop in document.getElementsByName in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xslt

I am trying to access to each node by elementName using following Javascript code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var h1 = document.getElementsByName("demoNode");
  for (var i = 0; i < h1.length; i++) {
    if (h1[i].name == "demoNode") {
      var att = h1[i].createAttribute("class");
      att.value = "democlass";
      h1[i].setAttributeNode(att);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.democlass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>

<p>Click the button to create a "class" attribute with the value "democlass" and insert it to the H1 element above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

The code should color the header text to red color. But it seems not to be working for me. Would you please let me know why? Here is the link to the demo from [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2gvg5xkf/4/)

Comment: Just as a note, the `if` condition is redundant as you are already getting all elements in the document matching that name so do not need to check the name again

Comment: @wmash There are some other nodes which I deleted t simplify my demo. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To get the name's attribute value, use `h1[i].getAttribute("name")`
- To set the attribute class, use `h1[i].setAttribute("class","democlass")`

Also, you do not need the if condition as the elements you are getting are already using name.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var h1 = document.getElementsByName("demoNode");
  for (var i = 0; i < h1.length; i++) {
     h1[i].setAttribute("class", "democlass");
  }
}
```

```css
.democlass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>

<p>Click the button to create a "class" attribute with the value "democlass" and insert it to the H1 element above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `for loop` you can use `map` also:

But first we need to convert instance of NodeList to array since `document.getElementsByName` returns nodelist.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var h1 = document.getElementsByName("demoNode");
  Array.prototype.map.call(h1, (key) => key.setAttribute('class','democlass'))
}
```

```css
.democlass {
    color: red;
 }
```

```html
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>

<p>Click the button to create a "class" attribute with the value "democlass" and insert it to the H1 element above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged jQuery I have created a jQuery snippet that will do the same thing as to what you are after. The benefit here is the `myFunction` does not need to be defined and it is less code in general. Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jr4frmww/13/)

**jQuery**

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("[name='demoNode']").each(function (elem) {
            $(this).addClass("democlass");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code contains few syntax errors.

You cannot retrieve or set attributes of elements by simply using `.`. So following code is wrong `h1[i].name` and it should be like this:

```
var val = h1[1].getAttribute("name");
   or
h1[1].setAttribute("name", "value");
```

And the other one is you don't need to create class attribute because it is primitive it always contain in every element. So you can simply assign your class name to it.

```js
function myFunction() {
   var h1 = document.getElementsByName("demoNode");
   
   for (var i = 0; i < h1.length; i++) {       
         h1[i].setAttribute("class", "democlass");
   }
}
```

```css
.democlass {
    color: red;
 }
```

```html
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
      <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
      <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
      <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
      <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
      <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
      <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>

      <p>Click the button to create a "class" attribute with the value "democlass" and insert it to the H1 element above.</p>

      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use property classList of HTMLElement and it's method add.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

```js
function myFunction() {
   var h1 = document.getElementsByName("demoNode");
   for (var i = 0; i < h1.length; i++) {
         h1[i].classList.add('democlass');
   }
}
```

```css
 .democlass {
    color: red;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
      <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
      <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
      <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
      <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
      <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
      <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>

      <p>Click the button to create a "class" attribute with the value "democlass" and insert it to the H1 element above.</p>

      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

And you need to choose load type "In head" for JS in JSFiddle in order to make your function available. https://jsfiddle.net/8s5fw33e/

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated the checking is redundant.

First, the `if` condition for checking the attribute name value is false. To get the attribute value you use `getAttribute("attribute_name")`.
The second part that doesn't work is
`h1[i].createAttribute()`

```js
function myFunction() {
   var h1 = document.getElementsByName("demoNode");
   for (var i = 0; i < h1.length; i++) {
   if (h1[i].getAttribute("name") == "demoNode") {
     var att = document.createAttribute("class");
     att.value = "democlass";
     h1[i].setAttributeNode(att);
   }
   }
}
//myFunction();
```

```css
.democlass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
<h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>

<p>Click the button to create a "class" attribute with the value "democlass" and insert it to the H1 element above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```